# Replace strings in text files with string literals and file names in powershell

Tags: string, powershell

My google-fu has failed me, so I'd love to get some help with this issue. I have a directory full of markup files (extension .xft). I need to modify these files by adding string literals and the filename (without the file extension) to each file.

For example, I currently have:

```
<headerTag>
<otherTag>Some text here </otherTag>
<finalTag> More text </finalTag>
```

What I need to end up with is:

```
<modifiedHeaderTag>
<secondTag> filenameGoesHere </secondTag>
<otherTag>Some text here </otherTag>
<finalTag> More text </finalTag>
```

So in this example,

```
"<modifiedHeaderTag>
<secondTag>"
```

would be my first string literal (this is a constant that gets inserted into each file in the same place),

```
filenameGoesHere
```

would be the variable string (the name of each file) and,

```
"</secondTag>"
```

would be my second constant string literal.

I was able to successfully replace text using:

```
(Get-Content *.xft).Replace("<headerTag>", "<modifiedHeaderTag>")
```

However, when I tried

```
(Get-Content *.xft).Replace("<headerTag>", "<modifiedHeaderTag> `n 
<secondTag> $($_.Name) </secondTag>")
```

I just got an error message. Replacing `$($_.Name)` with `${$_.Name)` also had no effect.

I've tried other things, but this method was the closest that I had gotten to success. I would appreciate any help that I can get. It's probably simple and I'm just not seeing something due to inexperience with Powershell, so a helping hand would be great.

If the above isn't clear enough, I'd be happy to provide more info, just let me know. Thanks everyone!

Comment: _I just got an error message._. You should include that so we don't have to guess

Comment: Your replace should work fine. You dont show the loop you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach, assuming you have all of the XFT's in one folder and you want to write the updates back to the same file:

```
$path = "C:\XFTs_to_Modify"

$xfts = Get-ChildItem $path -Include "*.xft"

foreach ($xft in $xfts) {
    $replace = "<modifiedHeaderTag>
<secondTag> $($xft.Name) </secondTag>"
    (Get-Content *.xft).Replace("<headerTag>", $replace) | Set-Content $xft.FullName -Force
}
```